# Commiato o comiato, congedo, e addio

Tags: word-meaning, difference, single-words

Mi è stato spiegato che un comiato è un  saluto per un periodo di tempo prima di rivedersi, che è diverso da un addio che è un saluto di chi non si vedrà mai più. Volevo chiedere se fosse veramente così. Grazie.

Comment: Hai consultato qualche vocabolario, visto che questa domanda riguarda solo il significato di tre parole?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Commiato](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/commiato/) (oggi si usa con due **m**) indica quando si lascia temporaneamente qualcuno, usato specialmente nella locuzione ***prendere commiato***.

[Congedo](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/congedo/) indica un allontanamento temporaneo e quindi può essere considerato un sinonimo di commiato, meno ricercato e di uso più comune.

[Addio](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/addio/) indica la situazione in cui si pensa di non incontrare più la persona. Nel caso, ad esempio, di un funerale si parla di ***ultimo commiato*** oppure addio, in quanto c'è la certezza.